# Is there simple syntax for declaring multiple keys with one value in perl?

Tags: perl, syntax, hashtable

Is there a simple way to declare a hash with multiple keys which all point to the same value in perl?

Here is something similar to what I'm looking for (I don't actually know if this works or not):

```
my $hash = {
             a, b, c => $valA,
             d, e, f => $valB
           };
```

such that....

```
print $hash->{a}; #prints $valA
print $hash->{b}; #prints $valA
print $hash->{c}; #prints $valA
print $hash->{d}; #prints $valB
print $hash->{e}; #prints $valB
print $hash->{f}; #prints $valB
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can write this:

```
my %hash;
$hash{$_} = $valA for qw(a b c);
$hash{$_} = $valB for qw(d e f);
```

Comment: I wish I'd put this in an answer instead of a comment. =P

Answer (score 13):

No, there is no simple syntax for this. (Actually, `=>` is documented to be an alias for `,` whose only formal effect is that it allows a bareword to the left of it even in strict mode).

The best you could do without defining your own subs might be something like

```
@hash{qw(a b c)} = ($valA) x 3 ;
@hash(qw(d e f)} = ($valB) x 3 ;
```

Answer (score 11):

I like to use a hash slice on one side and the list replication operator on the other. I use the scalar value of the keys array to figure out how many values to replicate:

```
 @hash{ @keys } = ($value) x @keys;
```

Comment: i like this solution, even when is slightly slower than $hash{$_} = $value for @keys;

Answer (score 6):

There is no built in syntax, but you can always write your own:

```
my $value = sub {map {$_ => $_[1]} @{$_[0]}};

my $hash = {
    [qw(a b c)]->$value('valA'),
    [qw(d e f)]->$value('valB'),
};

say join ', ' => map "$_: $$hash{$_}", sort keys %$hash;
# a: valA, b: valA, c: valA, d: valB, e: valB, f: valB
```

If you are going to be doing this a lot, you might want to look at `Hash::Util`'s `hv_store` function, which allows you to load multiple keys with exactly the same memory location.

Answer (score 4):

You can use hash slice assignment:

```
my $hash = {};

@$hash{a,b,c} = ($valA) x 3;
@$hash{d,e,f} = ($valB) x 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assignment can be done with statements too, such as with `map`. Here, map will expand into two lists.

```
my $hash = {
    ( map { $_ => $valA } ('a' .. 'c') ),
    ( map { $_ => $valB } ('d' .. 'f') ),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, as Henning Makholm pointed out, there is no direct shortcut, since `=>` is an alias for `,`.  The closest thing to a shortcut I can think of is:

```
foreach('a','b','c')
{
  $hash->{$_}=$valA;
}

foreach('d','e','f')
{
  $hash->{$_}=$valB;
}
```

Comment: `$hash->{$_} = $valA for ('a' .. 'c');` is even prettier.